# How to send emails to my user's friends?

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-graph-api

I've seen in a couple of Zynga games that they let you invite friends from Facebook, and that invitation goes directly to your email.

Is there any way to achieve this? Can I get the email addresses of my user's friends? I've tried the default Graph API calls with extended permissions but I wasn't able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: [Dev Facebook Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#user_friends_perms)

[image]

According to the above you cannot retrieve friend's email details even through extended permissions.

However you can always send requests to users using [facebook apprequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

This is how apprequests works

```
FB.init({
  appId  : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  frictionlessRequests : true,
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Dhiraj. I tried everything. There's a permission called "friends_about_me" That gives all information from user's friend (lots  of data) but, no email. I'm wondering how Zynga did it.

Comment: email would probably be the last thing fb will give to the app.

Comment: when you said invites, is it inviting a friend who has already used the app and inviting him to play that round(may be) or inviting them to install that app ?